# jQuery slider not working in FireFox

Tags: jquery, css, slider, jquery-animate

I have made a jQuery slider that works fine in Safari, Chrome and EI, but it does not render the animation at all in FF 3.6.28.

I am using two bits of code. One for when the page loads, and one for thumbnails. The first is:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{$("#hidden-1st").delay(1000).animate({ right: 10, width: '508px', 
            height: '286px' }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInQuint'})
  });
```

The code for clicking the thumbnail:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Thumb1").click(function () {
        $("#hidden-1st").css({ right: -508, width: '508px', height: '286px' })
                        .html('<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38581363?byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;autoplay=1" width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>')
                        .delay(1000)
                        .animate({ right: 10, width: '508px', height: '286px' }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'jswing'});
        $(".innerleftPlayer p").html("A personal profile of entrepreneur Mark Evans.<br/><br/> dur: 2:51")
    });
```

Here is the CSS:

```
#leftsidePlayer {
background-image:url(../images/playerLeftSideBG.jpg);
float:left;
height:236px;
width:158px;
position:relative;
padding: 25px;
}
.innerleftPlayer{
height: 236px;
width: 158px;
position:absolute;
display: table;
    }
.innerleftPlayer p{
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
font-family:Cuprum, sans-serif;
font-size:13pt;
color:#5f5f60;
    }
#rightsidePlayer {
background-color:#999;
float:left;
height:286px;
width:508px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#hidden-1st {
height:286px;
width:508px;
position:absolute;
right: -508px;
}

.inline {
float:left;
margin-right:8px;
}

#Thumb1,#Thumb2,#Thumb3,#Thumb4 {
float:left;
height:103px;
width:184px;
position:relative;
margin-right:30px;
}

.thumbsWrap {
width:826px;
height:103px;
background-image:url(../images/bannerBg.jpg);
position:relative;
padding:23px 57px;
}
```

and here is the mark up:

```
<div id="videoBox">
                <!--Player Begin-->
                <div id="outterGPlayerBox">
                    <div id="GPlayerBox">
                        <div id="leftsidePlayer">
                            <div class="innerleftPlayer">
                       <p>A personal profile of entrepreneur Mark Evans.<br/><br/> dur: 2:51</p>
                            </div>
                        </div><!--end of leftsidePlayer-->
                        <div id="rightsidePlayer">
                        <div id="hidden-1st"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38581363?byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="508" height="286" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe></div>  
                      </div><!--end of rightsidePlayer-->
                  </div><!--end of GPlayer Box-->   
                </div><!--end of outterGPlayerBox-->   
                <!--Player End-->
            </div><!--end of videoBox-->
```

Is this a problem with FF? Is there a fix? Or does my code need fixing?

Comment: In the future, you might find it easier to show your web-code working together by putting them into jsfiddle. That way people can play with your code themselves, live: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Please provide the full mark-up for us to understand what's happening. Your markup doesn't even have the #Thumb1 div. Follow theJollySin's advice, it will help you and us, in many ways.

Comment: Is it showing any errors in Firefox console tab?

Comment: sorry guys. you can see the full markup here http://www.doublezerofilms.com/videowebSamples.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem may lie in the fact that you're sending an integer to your `animate` function for the `right` parameter. You'll need to add `px` to the end of that integer for it to be cross-browser compatible.

```
$("#hidden-1st").delay(1000).animate({ right: '10px', width: '508px', height: '286px' }, { duration: 1000, easing: 'easeInQuint'});
```

Comment: hmm, thank you, its done something for it anyway. The slide function happens sometimes, but when it does it ends in a very clunky flash. How can I smooth this out?